# Converting aggregate output to wide format

Tags: r, reshape2

I used the function aggregate to make a long-format data-frame but a colleague needs to work with it in Excel. I'm finding it tricky to convert to wide format. I need to make the column "variable" and "Type" into several columns, each for the members they contain (Frontal, Parietal and Occipital) and (alpha, beta, gamma, delta and theta).

```
dput(head(aggdata))
structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", 
"theta"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("C", "N"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Frontal", 
    "Parietal", "Occipital"), class = "factor"), Condition = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), value = c(0.0947259533333333, 0.0489575420666667, 
    0.0686301660666667, 0.0754647909333333, 0.0708219834666667, 
    0.0644100006)), .Names = c("Time", "Type", "Group", "variable", 
"Condition", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can u show the expected otuput.  Did you meant `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(aggdata), Time + Group ~Type + variable, value.var = "value")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the `reshape2` package, and the dcast and melt functions.
What you have here is a nice molten data set, that you want to cast.

Let me alterate your sample data first as it doesn't give several variables to spread.

```
agg_data <- rbind(agg_data,head(agg_data,1))
agg_data$variable[7] <- "Parietal"
agg_data$value[7] <- 0.0686301660666667
agg_data

# Time  Type Group variable Condition      value
# 1    1 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.09472595
# 2    2 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.04895754
# 3    3 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.06863017
# 4    4 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.07546479
# 5    5 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.07082198
# 6    6 alpha     C  Frontal         1 0.06441000
# 7    1 alpha     C Parietal         1 0.06863017
```

and here's the line I think you want:

```
dcast(agg_data, Time  + Type + Group + Condition ~  variable)

# Time  Type Group Condition    Frontal   Parietal
# 1    1 alpha     C         1 0.09472595 0.06863017
# 2    2 alpha     C         1 0.04895754         NA
# 3    3 alpha     C         1 0.06863017         NA
# 4    4 alpha     C         1 0.07546479         NA
# 5    5 alpha     C         1 0.07082198         NA
# 6    6 alpha     C         1 0.06441000         NA
```

On the left side you put the data you want to aggregate on, on the right side you pur the variable you want to spread, you can put a sum of variables on the right side as well to spread on several variables, for example:

```
dcast(agg_data, Time  + Group + Condition ~  variable + Type)

# Time Group Condition Frontal_alpha Parietal_alpha
# 1    1     C         1    0.09472595     0.06863017
# 2    2     C         1    0.04895754             NA
# 3    3     C         1    0.06863017             NA
# 4    4     C         1    0.07546479             NA
# 5    5     C         1    0.07082198             NA
# 6    6     C         1    0.06441000             NA
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! The syntax looks nice and simple too :-)